# Downcasting baseclass into derived generic type C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I am struggling with an issue related with conversion between generic, possibly it's an easy one.
Basically I want to create a list of base class and add into it multiple classes.

```
public interface IQueryEngineDependency
{
    public IEnumerable<QueryDependencyDetail> GetDependencies<>();
}

public abstract class QueryDependencyDetail
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey> : QueryDependencyDetail
        where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public virtual Func<TEntity, object> Key { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Data { get; set; }

    public Func<TEntity, object> JoinKey { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> WhereClause { get; set; }   
}
```

**Problem**

I have a class, per example, that implements the interface shown above but I am figuring it out the right way to implement this.

```
public class TestQueryDependency : IQueryEngineDependency
{
        public IEnumerable<QueryDependencyDetail> GetDependencies()
        {
            var dependencies = new List<QueryDependencyDetail>
            {
                new QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks, long>
                {
                    Order = 1,
                    Data = null // just to simplify
                }
            };

            return dependencies;
        }
}
```

If I call the method `GetDependencies` somewhere in the code how can I make the downcasting to access the generic type fields? I mean I will get the instances of `QueryDependencyDetail` type. Then is it possible to convert it to `QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>`?
Or is there another way to do this?

**EDIT**

```
var testDep = new TestQueryDependency();
var dependencies = testDep.GetDependencies();
```

Remember that dependencies may have up to 20 different instances in my particular implementation.
How can I access the Data field, per example? (Just a simple scenario)

```
var first = dependencies.FirstOrDefault()?.Data; ?????
```

I will need this to perform dynamic queries using LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not getting any issue with your code. What you mean by down casting. Could you please elaborate the question

Comment: I am gonna edit the question to make it more explicit. Tks

Comment: If someone calling GetDependencies expects a `QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>`, and not a `QueryDependencyDetail` then *that's what the method needs to return*.  Otherwise it might simply not be a `QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>` instance and there will be nothing you can to do change that.

Comment: The relationship between `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>` is similar. `IQueryable` has an `ElementType` property and `IQueryable<T>` implementations return `typeof(T)`. If `GetDependencies` can return multiple `QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>` objects of different close-constructed types, having `EntityType` and `KeyType` properties in `QueryDependencyDetail` might enable you do all the reflection and expression-building that's needed. However, without knowing *how* you plan to use it *"to perform dynamic queries using LINQ"*, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: @madreflection I had already tried it as well.

I had the following method signature

public IEnumerable<QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>> GetDependencies<TEntity, TKey>() 
            where TEntity : BaseEntity;

But when you implement this method, what type would you use to create the List?
I tried the BaseEntity<TKey> or just the generic types attached to the method but i was not able to add something like this:

new QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks, long> { ... } saying types are not compatible, even though Tasks derives from BaseEntity<long>

Comment: You tried what Servy suggested (or something close to it). I'm talking about something entirely different.

Comment: @Servy take a look on my last comment please

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include *how* you intend to use the returned sequence (as shown in the question, not the variation in the comments). There's no way to know how to change it if you don't know what you need from it to build the query expression.

Comment: A `List<Fruit>` is not a `List<Apple>` and you can't act like it is. You can try to cast your `Fruit`s to `Apple`s, which may or may not work. The LINQ methods [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Cast__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) and [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) might help you. I begin to think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just cast it, i.e. `(QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity, TKey>) myObject`

However, you must make sure that the type actually match the real object. Lets take a simplified example:

```
    public class A { }
    public class B<T> : A { }
    public static B<T> Test<T>(A a) => (B<T>)a;
```

and

```
    var a = new B<int>();
    var b1 = Test<int>(a); // works since a is of type of B<int>
    var b2 = Test<string>(a); // Will throw invalid cast exception since a is not of type B<string>
```

You can also test the type:

```
if(a is B<int> b)
```

The problem here is that you have to know the actual type of the object. You cannot just cast `a` to `B<T>` without somewhere declaring what `T` actually is.

The solution I have used for these kind of problems is to avoid anything that needs to know the generic type. Make sure the interface or base class contain all methods you ever need when interacting with the object. This can be a bit complicated when multiple classes are involved, but it is usually possible.

**edit:**
A third option could be to use reflection. This can allow you to inspect the actual types of the generic type parameters. It may allow for things like creating another object with the same generic type parameter. The downside is that using reflection can be quite cumbersome and may be error prone and slow.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. When you call the method you don't know or might not have the TEntity or TKey to make that explicit cast you've suggested. I can check it out with multiple if ( a is B<int> b).. But that's the approach I was trying to avoid

Comment: Let's start with those multiple `if` statements. What would each of them look like? Not just the tests, but what you would do for each type you tested. Add it to the question. That would be the basis of an answer that doesn't require knowledge of specific types and the `if` statements to handle them individually.

Comment: @madreflection tks for you insistence to help me out with this one. Basically, after that I want to build an engine capable of join multiple IQueryable dynamically. Like I've mentioned in the description I got stucked because I need to access the fields within the generic type implementation. I am not sure if once get through this I will able to process the joins like I thought initially.

Comment: That's all well and good, but you're not providing any details, only high-level descriptions, and you're not doing what you need to do, which is *add it to the question*. I believe I can help you but I'm not going to guess. If you knew you had a `QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks, long>` in the returned sequence, what would you do with it?? Show the *code* that answers that question.

Comment: @madreflection I've edited the description with a simple scenario.

Comment: @Tiago Mourão your example is not very helpful. If the Data can be of any type, what will you do with it? you do not know what type it is! You could add a `object Data` property to the base type, but you still do not know the type!

Comment: @TiagoMourão, maybe I should have been more clear with my question: what would you do with it *"to perform queries using LINQ"* (forget about dynamic)? I concur with JonasH: if all you want to do is access the `Data` property, you don't need it to be generic. I asked what you would do if you knew you had a `QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks, long>`. How would you build a query with its properties if you knew you were dealing with that specific, close-constructed type? If any of the properties aren't used by your example, remove them from the type.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. So far, it's too minimal to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

What if you put the generic arguments on the engine interface?

```
public interface IQueryEngineDependency<TEntity,TKey> where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey> {
    public IEnumerable<QueryDependencyDetail<TEntity,TKey>> GetDependencies();
}
```

Then you can create a test engine:

```
public class TestQueryDependency : IQueryEngineDependency<Tasks,long> {
    public IEnumerable<QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks,long >> GetDependencies() {
        var dependencies = new[] {
                new QueryDependencyDetail<Tasks, long> {
                    Order = 1,
                    Data = null // just to simplify
                }
            };

        return dependencies;
    }
}
```

Comment: the list it's supposed to have Tasks or any other domain object dependency. I could not restrict the return object for tasks only. The only doubt is when you get the list of the base class, let's say, in the app startup. How can I access the Data field per example? At that point only have access to Order field.